# cpp multipleThread: detach non-class type error

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, compiler-errors, detach

I'm writing a program with **mutiplethread** using **cpp** , but I have a compiler-error like this:
[image: error message]
my code could be presented as follow:

```
    //A.hpp
    class ControleCam{
    public:
    ControleCam();
    ~ControleCam();
    };

    //A.cpp
    #include "A.hpp"
    ControleCam::ControleCam(){
    ...
    }
    ControleCam::~ControleCam(){
    ...
    }
    //B.cpp
    #include <A.hpp>
    int main(){
    std::thread turnCam(ControleCam());
    turnCam.detach();
    }
```

So anybody have a clue about where I did wrong and what can I do?

Comment: For next time, prefer to copy the error as text and paste here, rather than images.

Comment: OK! sorry for that, I thought that would be more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::thread turnCam(ControleCam());
```

You've hit C++'s [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). The above declaration doesn't declare a `turnCam` as a `std::thread` object. Rather `threadCam` is declared as a function that returns a `std::thread`. Use an extra pair of parenthesis or use uniform brace initialization syntax.

```
std::thread turnCam{ControleCam()};
```

BTW, you will need to have an overloaded `operator()(...)` in your class for the above to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I've changed it as "turnCam{ControleCam()}" It works!

Comment: I have an operator() in the A.cpp, I didn't put it there cause I think that is not the part that goes wrong ;)

Comment: @Elsa, no problem! That was a good thing you did. I just added that line to cover that up, just in case. Well, I'm glad your problem is solved. Regards! :-)